# SQL Update trigger to raise an error if primary key changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table to input data and have a primary key defined for the table. I want to create a trigger to raise an error if the user is changing the primary key of this table. The below code does not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TRIGGER ztr_ro_update
ON ztb_ro
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Name FROM inserted) <> (SELECT Name FROM ztb_ro)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Can not change primary key',16,1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ztb_ro
        SET Modified_On = GETDATE(),
            Modified_By = SYSTEM_USER
        FROM ztb_ro A
        JOIN inserted B ON A.Name = B.Name
    END
END
```

Comment: Your trigger assumes that only a single row can be affected in an `UPDATE`; a fatal flaw.

Comment: Generally it's very difficult to change the value of a PK, as if it's being referenced by an FK, then the `UPDATE` would cause the FK `CONSTRAINT`s to fail. I suspect you are trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you'vr tagged [[tag:tsql]] and [[tag:postgresql-triggers]] here; PostgreSQL doesn't use T-SQL.

Comment: If you have primary keys being changed your data model integrity is compromised, probably this is not the problem you are trying to solve. Which database platform are you using, your tags are contradictory.

Comment: I am using TSQL.

Comment: Well my comments stand, @Yash . You assume only one row can be updated, and that your table `ztb_ro` can only ever contain one row, and likely this isn't a problem, due to your FK `CONSTRAINT`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample from the docs:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.objects  
      WHERE name = 'reminder' AND type = 'TR')  
   DROP TRIGGER Person.reminder;  
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER reminder  
ON Person.Address  
AFTER UPDATE   
AS   
IF ( UPDATE (StateProvinceID) OR UPDATE (PostalCode) )  
BEGIN  
RAISERROR (50009, 16, 10)  
END;  
GO  
-- Test the trigger.  
UPDATE Person.Address  
SET PostalCode = 99999  
WHERE PostalCode = '12345';  
GO
```

[UPDATED()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=UPDATE%20%28%20column%29%20can%20be%20used%20anywhere%20inside,if%20the%20insert%2Fupdate%2Fdelete%20operation%20is%20permissible%20or%20not.)